# Accessing an object from a vector of object pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, cinder

This is a bit code i'm having trouble with:

```
int pressedKey = event.getNativeKeyCode();

for (int i=0; i <= AllTriggerPads.size() ;i++) {
    if (AllTriggerPads[i]->get_key() == pressedKey){
        AllTriggerPads[i]->mBufferPlayerNode->start();
    }
}
```

the `get_key()` is getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1, ...)` Error.

I seem to have a referencing problem. I am using almost the same code in the mouseDown and the fileDrop function:

```
for (int i=0; i < AllTriggerPads.size() ; i++) {

    if (AllTriggerPads[i]->mRect.contains(event.getPos())) {
        AllTriggerPads[i]->mBufferPlayerNode->start();
    }
}
```

This works fine!

Sooooo, i guess i am using the AllTriggerPads vector (of obj pointers) not correctly. So I CAN use `AllTriggerPads[i]->mRect.contains(event.getPos())`
but I CANT use `AllTriggerPads[i]->get_key()`. And I CANT access the value itself by `AllTriggerPads[i]->key` 
I have tried it with `AllTriggerPads.at(i)` but then i get an out of range error which makes me wonder even more.

The AlltriggerPads was initialized with 
`vector<TriggerPad*> AllTriggerPads;`

So how can I access the key member?

Comment: `i <= AllTriggerPads.size()` is wrong. You should have an index that is less than size actually: `i < AllTriggerPads.size()`. Voting to close, because that's just a simple and basic error/misconception.

Answer (score 3):

You are having an off-by-one error.

```
for (int i=0; i <= AllTriggerPads.size() ;i++)
```

replace with

```
for (int i=0; i < AllTriggerPads.size(); ++i)
```

(The ++ thing is irrelevant, it's just better practice to always use pre-increment)

Comment: Oooooh, so der was no Object found at AllTriggerPads[0] ??? 
what is pre-increment anyway? Does it increment the counter before it does the { ... } part ?

Comment: @Steffen No, you got it wrong. There was an object at AllTriggerPads[0]. It's at AllTriggerPads[AllTriggerPads.size()] that there is no object: never, ever will there be an object at the index == size.

And in this particular case, pre-increment does nothing different from post-increment, except that it's "faster" (your compiler might optimize it to the same for the type int, but for iterators it might not)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access an array element which doesn't exist. That's why it throws `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Change the for loop conditional to

```
for (int i = 0; i < AllTriggerPads.size(); ++i) {
    if (AllTriggerPads[i]->get_key() == pressedKey) {
        AllTriggerPads[i]->mBufferPlayerNode->start();
    }
}
```

or if `C++11` support is enabled, simplify it to

```
for (auto i : AllTriggerPads) {
    if (i->get_key() == pressedKey) {
        i->mBufferPlayerNode->start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice suggestion of the range-based for loop